# How to disable authentication for one service in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application, in which most of the pages are secured (you need to log in to access them) using following security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
class SecurityConfiguration extends
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("myapp")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .withUser("guest")
            .password("guest")
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository =
            new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

In my application class, I have a service `publicData`, which I want to be accessible without authentication (even, if the user isn't logged in).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MyAppApplication {
    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String,Object> home() {
        final Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/publicData")
    public String publicData() {
        return ...;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(final Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

I tried

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/publicData").permitAll();
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: The order matters. Try to chain it after your `.authorizeRequests()` above. Idealy you are looking to have something similar to this: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/config/SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: Well to see if it works, just add the /publicData along with your index, home, etc.

Comment: @Vaelyr It doesn't. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` now returns `null` even after the user has logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a role with all permission to access and grant that access just in some methods using Spring security annotation
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Of course every user need to get this role automatically when he connect in your application.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/*"
      access="hasRole('admin')"/>
</http>
```

Then in your free access method

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

Comment: Your proposal seems promising. In my application, all configuration happens via annotations. How can I implement the `<http use-expressions...>...</http>` part in this case?

Comment: You need to add it in your spring-security xml. Read the documentation that I paste, everything is in there.